# Does 100 files of 50mb each cause the same wear than a single 5000mb file when being written to an HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, physical-wear

I want to know what causes more wear on the disk, not talking about SSD's and USB's, only normal HDD's if that matters.
Does the times written matter? Only the space occupied matter by the File matter? Or both?

Comment: There's little evidence that either cause any measurable wear at all. Why are you interested in this? I suspect you are actually interested in a different question and just are wording it this way?

Comment: It doesn't matter to the HDD.  Bits are Bits.

Comment: Because i've been messing with large amounts of small files, mostly collection of images, and wanted to know if that could wear the HDD faster than a packed .zip of those same files...
@Ramhound so, you're saying both cause the same wear?

Comment: Writing many smaller files would require more writes due to more index updates. But probably not enough to affect the overall life-span of the drive any differently.  Analogy: Would turning a light-switch on and off 100 times a day wear it out faster than once a day?  Probably. Is using it 100 times a day going to wear it out before you decide to replace it for other reasons? Probably not. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I see, but as you said, writting many files requires more writes, so it can affect the life-span of the drive right?
I understand the amount of smaller files may have to be extraordinary high, but that was the answer i was looking for.

Comment: @SomeNickName - 50 1KB files is 50KB to the HDD.  1 50KB files is 50KB to the HDD.  The HDD does not care.  That does not mean the filesystem cares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only wear on your hard drive is spindle bearings, arm bearings, motor coils, head coils and arm coils. The heads on a hard drive never touch the surface of the drive, so there shouldn't be any wear on the magnetic media. It's not like a tape drive that the heads touch the tape and every time you run the tape you wear off some coating. The electronics themselves don't care about how you read/write to the drive and there is no "electron" wear. ;-)  The bearings and coils (basically the whole drive) are rated for hundreds of thousands of hours of wear.

Comment: So, it doesn't matter how i write to the HDD?
It wears over-time and not by writing to it?
Can you explain your answer better, please?

Comment: There is wear and tear on the mechanical portion of the drive, but reading/writing/erasing does not affect the magnetic storage no matter how you do it. The mechanical portion is designed to be very robust. To compare I have many hard drives in servers that are continously beaten on all day long 24 hours a day. Big files, little files, millions of reads and writes. It is rare that one fails. The usual reason to get rid of them is because they are too small or too slow.